# In Samsung S4, App is not opening when we click on notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In my app I am sending GCM notification to device, when we click on notification it is not opening app in Samsung S4. Please any one help me.

Code:

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Main.class);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0111, notification);
```

Comment: Please!! check [**Getting Started with Android Push Notification : Latest Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) - step by step complete tutorial**](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2013/11/android-push-notification-google-cloud.html) may help you

Comment: ya those steps are completed,my requirement is,in s4 whenever we click on notifications it is not opening the app just hide the notification from notification bar

Comment: Did you checked all the steps, at the end I added code for launching activity when click on Notificatoin. I tested it on couple of Samsung devices and working well.

Comment: yes,it is working for samsung devices(s duos,grand) but not in s4

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250364/notification-click-not-launch-the-given-activity-on-nexus-phones for more information

Answer (score 6):

Add `android:exported="true"` in the AndroidManifest for the Activity specified by the intent.
This problem is dependent of Android Version not Samsung.......

Comment: where to add this permission ? in application tag or in GCMBaseIntentService in manifest ? i have alreday added same in GCMBaseIntentService still its not opening in S4 it gets opened in rest of the devices

Comment: @Richa add it to the activity started by the Intent, or in the above example, the `Main` Activity

Answer (score 0):

Add android:exported = "true" in the manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".G_chat"
            android:label="G_chat"
            android:exported="true">
</activity>
```

G_chat is the activity which will be opened on the notification click.