# Notification Click not launch the given Activity on Nexus Phones

Tags: android, events, notifications, click

I am using this code to show the local notification and When notification comes then on click of notification want to launch the ListActivity but on Google nexus device `ListActiviy` is not launches when click on notification, but on other device this code is working well.

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
            ListActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("clicked", "Notification Clicked");
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);   // To open only one activity on launch.
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, reqCode,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationManager nM = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context);

    notify.setContentIntent(pIntent);
    notify.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon);
    notify.setContentTitle("Hello World");
    notify.setContentText("");
    notify.setAutoCancel(true);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    notify.setSound(alarmSound);
    notify.setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 1000);
    nM.notify(reqCode, notify.build());
```

Adding logcat when the activity is not launched:

```
03-26 14:22:35.893: W/ActivityManager(515): Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.x.y/.music.ui.PlaybackActivity bnds=[42,101][636,186] (has extras) } from null (pid=-1, uid=10121) not exported from uid 10126
03-26 14:22:35.893: W/ActivityManager(515): Unable to send startActivity intent
03-26 14:22:35.893: W/ActivityManager(515): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.x.y/.music.ui.PlaybackActivity bnds=[42,101][636,186] (has extras) } from null (pid=-1, uid=10121) not exported from uid 10126
03-26 14:22:35.893: W/ActivityManager(515):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1186)
03-26 14:22:35.893: W/ActivityManager(515):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:741)
03-26 14:22:35.893: W/ActivityManager(515):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:3300)
03-26 14:22:35.893: W/ActivityManager(515):     at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:252)
03-26 14:22:35.893: W/ActivityManager(515):     at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.send(PendingIntentRecord.java:192)
03-26 14:22:35.893: W/ActivityManager(515):     at android.content.IIntentSender$Stub.onTransact(IIntentSender.java:64)
03-26 14:22:35.893: W/ActivityManager(515):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
03-26 14:22:35.893: W/ActivityManager(515):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which version nexus have? kitkat (4.4)?

Comment: ok that is a problem!!! see my answer

Comment: I also checked with nexus 5 (Kitkat 4.4) and nexus 4(with updated os kitkat 4.4.2),both give the same results.

Comment: ya that i am telling its problem of Kitkat version...!!!

Comment: you can try lower version than 4.4...eg.4.3 or 4.2 etc i think you are not see my answer that is an issue with Android os version kitkat

Comment: Yes, i saw your answer, so currently we should forget about this functionality on nexus kitkat, And it works good on lower versions.

Comment: thanks Hardik for replying...

Comment: My above code is working well for all OS version except Kitkat 4.4 and 4.4 +

Comment: On an Emulated 4.4, everything works fine - it's a problem with Nexus.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063678/permission-denial-starting-intent-from-null-pid-1-uid-10221-not-exported-fr/39555603#39555603

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My above code is working well for all OS version except Kitkat 4.4 and 4.4 +
But i have got solution i, put the receiver in another process and it works well for all most Android OS versions...

Like this way..

activity android:name=".NotifyReciever" android:process=":remote"

and we can learn more about processes here....

[Should I use android: process =":remote" in my receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311069/should-i-use-android-process-remote-in-my-receiver)

Answer (score 66):

This is reported issue for kitkat 4.4 not opening activity when click on notification here is an issue url

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63236

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61850

suggested workaround is to cancel existing `PendingIntent`, or use `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`

OR

Try below

Adding a flag in `Activity` in `AndroidManifiest.xml`

```
android:exported="true"
```

Comment: One of the suggestions in those links, adding *android:exported="true"* within "activity" tags for the target Activity fixed my problem on KitKat. Thank you for the links.

Comment: PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT Fixed my problem

Comment: This solved my issue on kitkat, however, I can only open the activity AFTER a restart of the device, has someone else encountered this? i.e before restarting the device I push on the notification and nothing happens, but after restart, if i push the button, it opens the activity

Comment: `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` fixed it for me on my Sony Xperia M running Android 4.3.

Answer (score 10):

This issue is known for Android Kitkat 4.4 and Lollipop.
Please add :

```
android:exported="true"
```

in android manifest inside activity tag which is supposed to be opened after tapping notification from status bar

Answer (score 3):

You can also add `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` to fix this.

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add android:exported = "true" in the manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".ListActivity"
            android:label="ListActivity"
            android:exported="true">
</activity>
```

ListActivity is the activity which will be opened on the notification click.

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by `mass` has worked for me and it's very simple, no need to change your code:

In your AndroidManifest.xml add the following attribute to your `<activity>` tag:

```
android:exported="true"
```

It has worked in a Samsung Galaxy Young 2 with Android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this

```
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);   // To open only one activity on launch.
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, reqCode,
        notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

to

```
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);   // To open only one activity on launch.
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, reqCode, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

it will work for all version even with Kitkat also.

**Note** :  Activity will be started outside of the context of an existing activity, so you must use the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK launch flag in the Intent.

Answer (score 0):

If `android:exported="true"` doesn't work for you, just redirect the intent from your LAUNCHER activity.

In your LAUNCHER activity check for incoming notifications as follows:

```
 if(getIntent().hasExtra("type") && getIntent().getStringExtra("type").compareTo("notification")==0){
        Intent redirect = new Intent(getIntent());
        redirect.setClass(this,YourNotificationActivity.class);
        startActivity(redirect);
 }
```

If you need to filter the intent then use:

```
 Intent incoming = getIntent();
 if(intent.hasExtra("type") && intent.getStringExtra("type").compareTo("notification")==0){
    Intent outgoing = new Intent(this, YourNotificationActivity.class);
    outgoing.putExtra("title", incoming.getStringExtra("title");
    outgoing.putExtra("content", incoming.getStringExtra("content");
    startActivity(outgoing);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help u.

long uniqueId=  System.currentTimeMillis();

```
    /** This is the part to let your application recognise difference notification when the user click on the notification.
     *  You could use any unique string to represent your notification. But be sure each notification have difference action name.
     **/
    taskDetailIntent.setAction("notifi" + uniqueId);


    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.
            getActivity(this, 0, taskDetailIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    /** Set the unique id to let Notification Manager knows this is a another notification instead of same notification.
     *  If you use the same uniqueId for each notification, the Notification Manager will assume that is same notification
     *  and would replace the previous notification. **/
    notificationManager.notify((int) uniqueId, builder.build());
```